# Async method with Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#

I dont have much experiance with async methods and I am not sure if I am using parallel for each correctly. In some cases I am getting Index out of range exception on the line with: "listPages.Add"

```
private static int SetPages(FileDocument document, List<PageDTO> pages, string tableName, Entities entity, int accessID)
{
   List<Page> listPages = new List<Page>();
            
    Parallel.ForEach(pages, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8 }, page =>
    {
        string docPath = GetPathString(page.PageID);
        if (File.Exists(docPath))
        {
            byte [] docBytes = ConvertToWebP(docPath);
            if(docBytes.Length > 0)
            {
                var fileStreamID = InsertInDatabase(docBytes, page.PageID, tableName);
                listPages.Add(SetPage(document, page.PageNumber, fileStreamID, tableName, accessID));
            }
        }
    });
            
    entity.FilePages.AddRange(listPages);
    return listPages.Count();
}
```

Comment: Your code isn't thread-safe. You should not be using shared mutable collections inside a `Parallel.ForEach` body.

Comment: Your method isn't async and it's static

Comment: _"Async method with Parallel.ForEach"_ - No. Just no. Don't. ;D

Comment: `Parallel` were designed for CPU bound operations so do not use for I/O bound async operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your code might meet racing-condition there are a lot of thread action with
`List<Page> listPages = new List<Page>()` , the `List<>` isn't  thread safe collection

I would use [ConcurrentBag<>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=net-6.0) instead of `List<>`, because `ConcurrentBag<>` is a thread safe collection.

> Represents a thread-safe, unordered collection of objects.

```
private static int SetPages(FileDocument document, List<PageDTO> pages, string tableName, Entities entity, int accessID)
{
    ConcurrentBag<Page> listPages = new ConcurrentBag<Page>()
    Parallel.ForEach(pages, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8 }, page =>
    {
        string docPath = GetPathString(page.PageID);
        if (File.Exists(docPath))
        {
            byte [] docBytes = ConvertToWebP(docPath);
            if(docBytes.Length > 0)
            {
                var fileStreamID = InsertInDatabase(docBytes, page.PageID, tableName);
                listPages.Add(SetPage(document, page.PageNumber, fileStreamID, tableName, accessID));
            }
        }
    });
            
    entity.FilePages.AddRange(listPages.ToList());
    return listPages.Count();
}
```